# Facebook LIKE BOX not retrieving id for my site

Tags: facebook, drupal, facebook-likebox

Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in. why am i I getting this when it works with other plugins?

Answer (score 0):

One can't tell the problem without seeing any code but i will tell you the simplest way to get a facebook likebox and check where the problem lies.

For setting a likebox on any particular page, you need to do following two things

1) Include the following javascript code which I think you should have

```
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

2) Paste the following code wherever you want to show the likebox

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/YourFacebookPage" 
      data-width="292" data-height="238" data-show-faces="true" 
      data-border-color="#CCC" data-stream="false" data-header="false">
</div>
```

**Remember**: The `data-href` should be your website **Page on facebook** and not the page-link itself